# Can I install ubuntu from a blu-ray disc?

Tags: installation, blu-ray

I only have blank blu-ray discs around , if i burn the iso to one of them would i be able to boot from it and install ubuntu?

I would rather not burn the disc without being sure, they cost quite a lot around here.

Comment: Of course I don't know the entirety of your situation, but in case you weren't aware, it is possible to [install Ubuntu using a USB drive](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick) or by [other methods that don't require a CD](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation%20without%20a%20CD).

Comment: I have already checked those methods but they are either too time-consuming (and i don't have all that much time today :S) or use floppies/usb/etc that i either don't have a drive for (floppy) or don't have around (usb drive)

Thanks though

Comment: get the iso you want, get a usb key, get unetbootin, choose the iso, let it cerate a bootable key..and done ,doesn't take more than 15 minutes

Comment: Just like i said above though, i didn't have a usb drive around. blu-ray disc worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you download the [DVD](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/dvd/current/) image, you can.

Comment: Is there any reason why i should use the dvd image?

Comment: You could. I thought you wanted a DVD image as well.

Comment: No I just have no CDs around and stores are closed today.(I always find the worst time to experiment on my system)